# _POSIX_* (limits.h) vs _SC_* (sysconf)

Tags: linux, posix

I just noticed **the macros named "_POSIX_*" in limits.h** are (namewise) similar to **the parameter of *sysconf* function**. For example, there is the macro named "_POSIX_ARG_MAX", and I can also call *sysconf* with the argument of "_SC_ARG_MAX". Why do we need *sysconf* in the first place when we're totally free to use the macros in limits.h?

Comment: The `_POSIX_*` ones are the minimum value that must be supported in order to conform to POSIX at all.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Thank you~! It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_POSIX_*` values are the minimum requirement to be POSIX compliant.  They will have the same value on all platforms.  The particular value supported by the implementation may be higher.

From `man sysconf`:

> For variables or limits, typically, there is a constant `_FOO`, maybe defined in `<limits.h>`, or `_POSIX_FOO`, maybe defined in `<unistd.h>`.  The constant will not be defined if the limit is unspecified.  If the constant is defined, it gives a guaranteed value, and a greater value might actually be supported.  If an application wants to take advantage of values which may change  between  systems, a call to `sysconf()` can be made.  The `sysconf()` argument will be `_SC_FOO`.

For example, `_POSIX_ARG_MAX` is 4096.  But `sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX)` may return a larger number if the system supports it.